# click on div which is under div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got situation:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

On my web page, element `B` is under `A`. How can I bind click to only those A element which are above B elements? For example:

```
$('#main, #main > #b').click(function(){
  //something
});
```

**EDIT2:** this code is OK when I click on parent div, or "b" element but when I click on "A" element which is above nothing happens.

in general I want to click only on B element, but when A element is above B I want to fire up event to.
thanks!

**EDIT:** unfortunately I cannot modify HTML code.

Comment: "but when I click on "A" element which is above "A" element nothing happens" ?

Comment: Incredibly confusing question.

Comment: Let's suppose that A element is layer on whole website, and under it (by z-index) there are few B elements. I wanna to fire up event only when B element are clicked, but becouse of the A element I have to bind click on A element only when B is under it.

Comment: very difficult question to understand. but if i understood well, then you can use `.hover()` function to achieve the results. For example, when you hover your B item which is above the A, then you add to B element `z-index:1` and to A element - `z-index:-1`, and on hover out functon you put everything to the default state. hope you get an idea

Comment: `on my webpage` + `unfortunately I cannot modify HTML code` = not really your page, huh?

Comment: @aspirinemaga I will try it thanks! i didnt thought about it thanks!.

Comment: @RASG its for my project it was a shorthand. ;)

Comment: @Krystian - answer added, take a look on it, it will give you a better visibility to your idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, as i left a comment in your question, i made a script to show you what i've mean by using jquery library for example, [HERE IS THE LINK](http://jsbin.com/ufuwek/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main div{width:100px;height:100px;display:block;position:absolute;margin:10px;top:0;left:0;line-height:100px;text-align:center;}
#main #a{background:#DDD;top:5px;left:5px;}
#main #b{background:#999;color:#FFF;}
```

jquery script:

```
//onHover B do the next...
$('#b').hover(function(){

  // actual B element move below
  $(this).css('zIndex', -1);

});
//onHover A do the next...
$('#a').hover(function(){
  // nothing on hover
},function(){
  // but onHoverOut do next...
  $('#b').css('zIndex', 'auto');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't a clue *why* you're doing this, but nonetheless…

```
$('#a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#b').click();
});
```

Comment: it could be done like this, but the "A" element is much more bigger then "B" so I cannot fire it up every time when someone click on this element. Only in described earlier situation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
</div>​
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main div").each(function() {

        // bind each div to the click event
        $(this).click(function() {
            alert("hah!");
        });

        // if we have reached "b", stop binding events to any following divs
        if ($(this).attr('id') == "b") {
          return false;
        }

    });
});
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/U6J8c/